# How to get nested FormControl?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-forms

This is my form structure:

```
form = new FormGroup({
name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
comment: new FormControl(''),
endpointsPermissions: new FormControl({
  read: new FormControl(null),
  write: new FormControl(null)
}),
exportDefinitionsPermissions: new FormControl({
  read: new FormControl(null),
  write: new FormControl(null)
}),
sourcesPermissions: new FormControl({
  read: new FormControl(null),
  write: new FormControl(null)
})
```

});

and I tried to use it in my html-file like this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" fxFlex="100">
    <mat-checkbox [formControl]="form.get('endpointsPermissions').value.read">{{"ROLES.READ" | translate}}</mat-checkbox>
</mat-form-field>
```

but its not working and the errors I get are:

> control.registerOnChange is not a function

> mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.

So how do i use [formControl] with nested FormControls correctly.

Comment: This issue is not due to formcontrol. Make sure you have imported all material modules like MatInputModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatCheckboxModule etc

Comment: I did, I also use <input matInput formControlName="comment"> and it does work, only when i use [formControl] these errors appear.

Comment: Share stackblitz if possible or Share html code here

Comment: Shared the html below

Comment: "angular 2" is an outdated name. This is [tag:angular] as opposed to [tag:angularjs]

Comment: @eL_ if you want to share your html, edit the question. Do no add details into answers

Answer (score 0):

mat-checkbox does not work inside mat-form-field. Refer to this to see which element works inside mat-form-field. https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview

Proper way for nested form is

```
form = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        comment: new FormControl(''),
        endpointsPermissions: new FormGroup({
            read: new FormControl(null),
            write: new FormControl(null)
        }),
        exportDefinitionsPermissions: new FormGroup({
            read: new FormControl(null),
            write: new FormControl(null)
        }),
        sourcesPermissions: new FormGroup({
            read: new FormControl(null),
            write: new FormControl(null)
        })
    });
```

and

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlex formGroupName="endpointsPermissions">
        <h2 mat-dialog-title>Permission</h2>
        <!-- Endpoints -->
        <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex fxLayoutGap="16px">
            <span>Endpoints Permission</span>
            <mat-checkbox matInput formControlName="read">Read</mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This works now (thanks to Eliseo):

```
form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    comment: new FormControl(''),
    endpointsPermissions: new FormGroup({
        read: new FormControl(null),
        write: new FormControl(null)
    }),
    exportDefinitionsPermissions: new FormGroup({
        read: new FormControl(null),
        write: new FormControl(null)
    }),
    sourcesPermissions: new FormGroup({
        read: new FormControl(null),
        write: new FormControl(null)
    })
});
```

```
<mat-checkbox [formControl]="form.get('endpointsPermissions.read')">{{"ROLES.READ" | translate}}</mat-checkbox>
```